# Trigger Bigquery Scheduled Queries from Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I need to run some Scheduled Queries on-demand.
I believe Cloud Functions triggered by Pubsub events is a solution that provides good decoupling.

However, I can't find a reliable solution.

This solution crashes
[BigQuery + Cloud Functions:](https://towardsdatascience.com/bigquery-cloud-functions-how-to-run-your-queries-as-soon-as-a-new-google-analytics-table-is-17fbb62f8aaa)

This one works only on the documentation page
[Method: transferConfigs.startManualRuns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/startManualRuns?authuser=1)

What is the best way to trigger On-Demand Scheduled Queries from cloud function?

Comment: When you say "this solution crashes", what do you see that make you think it's crashing? Why is it not working?

Comment: @DustinIngram the crash happens in 'project_transfer_config_path' with error message that this function is not part of client.

Comment: Can you include the code that is crashing as well as the entire stack trace in your question?

Comment: You mean that you need a scheduled query (for example trigger every day) and for user convenience you want to trigger it on-demand, right?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere no, I would like to run a query on-demand. Everytime a particular event happens in the system this query needs to run to update a table.

Comment: @DustinIngram this is the error: parent = client.project_transfer_config_path(projectid, transferid) AttributeError: 'DataTransferServiceClient' object has no attribute 'project_transfer_config_path'

Comment: @DustinIngram to explain a little better. All this pain is because I need to sync a google drive spreadsheet to a table. Other analysts will use the information. It would be interesting to sync on demand, but I can't figure out how to give my Cloud Function permission to access the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

I understood that you don't want a schedule queries, you want a query to easily invoque, without rewriting it.

I can propose 2 solutions:

1. store your query in a file on Cloud Storage. When you invoque your Cloud Function, you read the file content and you perform a bigQuery job on it.

- PRO: you simply have to update the file content to update the query.
- CONS: you need to read a file from storage and then to call BigQuery -> 2 API to calls and a query file to manage

2. Use [stored procedure](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#beginexception)

- Firstly, create your stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `my_project.my_dataset.my_procedure`() 
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`;
  .......
END;
```

- Then invoke it in your Cloud Function (It's a query to BigQuery

```
CALL `my_project.my_dataset.my_procedure`();
```

- PRO: Simply update the stored procedure to update the query. Can perform complex queries
- CONS: you don't have a query history (you can activate the bucket versioning in the previous solution for this)

---

Are they acceptable solutions?

Comment: Interesting... for the second solution, how would I call the procedure with Python in cloud function?

Comment: It's a query!! Perform a bigQuery query with the CALL procedure content.

Comment: Those solutions would work. However, it seems I can't give my cloud function permission to access the spreadsheet gets the information in the first place. The only way to decouple it is with the scheduled queries.

Comment: Ok, you have an external table on Sheet, right?

Comment: Yes, I have a table that is directly linked to a Google Drive Spreadsheet. Than I run a script that creates another table that copy the spreadsheet.